# Benchmarking: parts don't add up to the whole

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, benchmarking

I'm playing around with benchmarking in order to see how much of the pie my custom javascript takes up vs the things out of my control as far as optimization is concerned: dom/network/painting, etc.

I would use chrome's dev tools for this, but i don't see an accurate pie chart since my functions do ajax calls and therefore network is added to the javascript portion of the pie (as well as dom and other 'out of my control' stuff).

I'm using benchmarkjs (http://benchmarkjs.com/) to test this line:
 `document.querySelector("#mydiv").innerHTML = template(data);`

where `template` is a precompiled handlebars template.

To the question...

I've broken the process down into 3 parts and took the mean of each run:

1. `document.querySelector("#mydiv")` - 0.00474178430265463
2. `myDiv.innerHTML = already_called_template` - 0.005627522903454419
3. `template(data)` - 0.004687963725254854

But all three together (the one liner above) turns out to be: 0.005539341673858488

Which is less than the lone call to set innerHTML.

So why don't the parts equal the sum? Am I doing it wrong?

---

Sample benchmark below (i'm using deferred as a constant because i plan to add ajax next):

```
var template = Handlebars.compile(html);
var showStats = function(e) { console.log(e.target.stats.mean); };
var cachedDiv = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
var cachedTemplate = template(data);

new Benchmark('just innerHTML', function(deferred) {
  cachedDiv.innerHTML = cachedTemplate;
  deferred.resolve();
}, {defer: true, onComplete: showStats}).run();

new Benchmark('full line', function(deferred) {
  document.querySelector('#myDiv').innerHTML = template(users);
  deferred.resolve();
}, {defer: true, onComplete: showStats}).run();
```

Comment: Didn't you say you didn't want to measure DOM things?

Comment: Hi Bergi, I wanted to be able to measure dom/network/customjs separately. My goal was to sum them up to make sense of the total time, but it's not quite adding up...

Answer (score 0):

http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html

Turns out the jit is probably doing some crazy sh.... stuff.

The answer would be to try to outsmart it, but I think I should adjust my strategy instead.